# Problem using Flexbox and Unordered List for Nav Bar

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a fixed horizontal nav bar, including a logo image and an unordered list for navigation links.

I want to use Flexbox for improved responsiveness, and because it seemed like a simpler option.

I just need the logo to stay on the right side, and the navbar to sit next to it with even spacing between links.

It's two flexboxes nested within another fixed flexbox.  It took me forever to get them to sit next to each other instead of in a column. Now the li items are refusing to respond to justify-content.
I might be completely incorrect in my current approach; however I've tried so many times and this is as close as I can get.

```css
html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #e8e8e8;
}

#header-img {
  border: solid 1px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  border: solid 1px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

li {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="container">
    <img id="header-img" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/09cucxl9sq8stvt/LogoMakr_7edr0A.png?raw=1">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Profile</li>
      <li>Logout</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

As you can see, it's extremely simple. All solutions I've found online seem helpful until I try them and it does not come out as described.

I don't know if it's the combination of flexboxes and the ul, if it's the fixed positioning of the header, or my own stupidity.

I am aware of grid layouts, etc., but really want to familiarise myself with flexboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to tell the menu to take up the remaining space by adding `flex:1` otherwise it will default to only as much space as it can collapse to.

```css
html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #e8e8e8;
}

#header-img {
  border: solid 1px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  border: solid 1px;
}

ul {
  flex: 1;
  /* this */
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

li {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="container">
    <img id="header-img" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/09cucxl9sq8stvt/LogoMakr_7edr0A.png?raw=1">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Profile</li>
      <li>Logout</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. This also works to get the boxes on the same line and distributes the links, however justify-content still does nothing, no effect when I change it or remove it. Having trouble understanding why...

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem lies in your "ul" width being too small and you're using justify-content on "ul" instead of "li". Use this instead:

```
    ul {
        list-style: none;
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
    }

    li {
        flex: 1;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this and it works, however, justify-content still doesn't seem to affect the links. When I change it to flex-end or anything else, nothing changes...

Comment: It is working fine for me. Use the <a> tags inside the <li> tags. If you put the <li> tags inside <a> tags use justify-content on the <a> tags.